# USB Device not Recognized in front USB port but works on backside USB port

Tags: windows-7, tablet

I just connect my `Motorola Xoom Tablet` to my front side of `Windows 7 PC` It raises

[image: Error]

But, when i connect this into backside. It's working fine. This happens only for this device only. My other devices are working fine in both side of my PC. What happens inside? I don't know hardware. Can anyone tell me about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is likely due to the front ports on your PC being either lower speed or lower power than the rear ports.  If the Xoom cannot communicate fast enough or get enough power from the computer it will likely have trouble getting the computer to recognize it correctly as you've experienced.

Port specifics should be possible to find with the model info of your computer.